# Mobile Device Management

Tags: java, php, android, mdm

Is there a way to control an android device from an admin web interface using a php code? I have tried looking into other MDM platforms however they have a lot of requirements to be installed.

Comment: What do you mean by control an android device ?

Comment: Like able to access it and press things on it. Basically remote controlling.

Comment: Press things on it? Press???

Comment: Like clicking on applications

Answer (score 0):

This is possible up to certain limit, like Run a certain app, delete files, create files , taking pictures, play video/audio .. anything that doesn't need users extended permission.

1. You need to create an app that has ability to perform what ever the task you need.
2. You can send an action through (SMS/notification) etc to the device.
3. Your app will take a action and do the necessary changes of the device.